# How can I stop airflow from the attic through the gap of a pocket door?

Tags: doors

I have a sliding door in the second floor of my house. When I get close to it I can smell attic-like odor. When I put my hand on the gap I can feel very slight airflow.

Is there any way to fix it? Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Is the air from one or both of those two black sections?  Not sure what attic smells like, but air flow from walls inside a house means bad sealing somewhere usually.  A picture of a larger area might help, maybe pointing where the air is coming from.

Comment: I am not sure about the smell either, but it was the same odor when I open the doors to the attics. I suspect it was old wood or insulation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First question to ask is: which way is the air flowing? Light a match and move it towards the gap. The flame will bend towards the same direction of the air flow (if it's difficult to see, blow out the match and watch where the smoke goes).

If the air is flowing **into** the gap, it is likely due to convection, with warm air being drawn up into the attic. You'll want to check there next. Take the matches with you and verify the air is flowing **out** of the pocket and **into** the attic. If so, you'll want to try and figure out where the air is entering the attic and try sealing that gap from above. Be prepared to discover that the air is moving through more than just one opening.

If the air is flowing **out** of the gap, then you need to figure out where it's flowing *from* so you can work back to the source. An adjacent room might be a bit more air-tight and be at just a higher enough pressure to be pushing air through the gap. Again, take your matches and see if you can figure it out. How to seal it up will depend on what you discover.

Hope this helps. Keep us posted.

Comment: Thanks! I will try that!

Answer (score 1):

I agree with [mynameistaken](https://diy.stackexchange.com/users/163810/mynameistaken) that you probably have **poor air sealing above**. Back when, the only such seal was crated by the plaster, which wouldn't continue through the wall. Small gaps in framing could explain the leak. If you have a more modern home the same situation could occur if no vapor barrier was installed in that area (which wouldn't be uncommon--it's usually placed inside each room). The only practical way to fix that is from the attic.

I would go exploring up there. Use proper breathing and eye protection, along with suitable clothing, to protect against irritable dust. Find the area where the wall is located and see what you see.

From there, you may need to temporarily move insulation, and then you can apply poly sheeting or other barriers to airflow. You may need to caulk such sheeting to framing, or you may be able to stop the gap with caulk or spray foam alone.